# Is there a way for someone to read my contract?

Tags: solidity

I made a Contract, "AA" then deployed it. I think, people can execute my Contract's function, but they can't read whole contents in my Contract. Can people know the details of my contract? (e.g. using web3...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are decompilers (such as [this one](https://etherscan.io/bytecode-decompiler)) that can convert the deployed bytecode to a pseudocode. So while it's not possible to get the exact same Solidity code, anyone can still get a rough idea of what the contract does.